# How to display a Textbox when a Radio Button is checked using jquery in MVC4?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi all i have some radio buttons and text boxes corresponding to each radio button..what i want to do is when an radio button is checked show the corresponding textbox from the following format..

```
        @foreach(var item in Viewbag.Ids)
        {
         <div class="group">
          <label class="label">
           @Html.RadioButton("Rdbtn",new{value=@item.value})
          </label>
            <div class="control">
                  <input type="text"  />
            <div>
        </div>
```

in another case

```
       <div>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.IsFlat)
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.IsFree)
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.IsTax)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Products)
       </div>
```

what am i doing for the above only one of the radio button has to be checked when one is checked the other should be unchecked i am doing it like this

```
   $('input[type=radio]').change( function(){
    if(this.checked)
        {
                  $(this).closest('div').find('input[type=radio]').not(this).attr('checked',false)
        }
     });
```

this is working fine and i want to dsiplay the  dropdwon when an "  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.IsTax)" is checked how can i do this and i have to get the radio button checked in edit mode if it is checked can any one help me in doing this

i have to get the radio boxes checked if they are checked at the time of insertion at the time of edit i ahve to dsiplay them checked and if @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.IsTax) is selected in edit mode i have to check that radiobutton and dsiplay the dropdown

Comment: if you give the radio a group (same name) you won't have to manually uncheck the other radios

Comment: i tried that its not working as i am using model there..

Comment: but its working in the first condition...

Comment: can any one help me with the jquery operations pleasee..

Comment: If you show the generated HTML I can probably help get you on your way

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039225/how-to-decollapse-section-if-radiobutton-is-checked-in-form/19039942#19039942  see my answer on this question.  hopefully there is something there that will help