# How to decollapse section if radiobutton is checked in form

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I simple want to know how to collapse a div section when a radiobutton like below is checked

Radiobutton that I want checked to collapse a section

```
<div>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Transaction.PaymentProvider, "2")
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Transaction.PaymentProvider, "Pay with Credit Card")
</div>
```

Section that I wanted collapse if Radiobutton above is checked

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="middle">
        <tr>
            <td width="100" border="0" class="paylabel">Card Number:</td>
            <td colspan="3" width="335" border="0" class="paylabel">
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Transaction.CreditCard.CardNumber)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Transaction.CreditCard.CardNumber)
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I am using bootstrap and tried the accordion classes but that only works with a hyperlink and I'm not sure how to make a condition if that radiobutton is checked then decollapse

```
<label class="radio">
<input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PaymentProvider must be a number." data-val-required="The PaymentProvider field is required." id="Transaction_PaymentProvider" name="Transaction.PaymentProvider" type="radio" value="1"/>
<label for="Transaction_PaymentProvider">Pay with PayPal</label>
 <input id="Transaction_PaymentProvider" name="Transaction.PaymentProvider" type="radio" value="2" />
<label for="Transaction_PaymentProvider">Pay with Credit Card</label>
 </label>
```

this is the code that is being debugged from IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using info from here [jQuery click event on radio button doesn't get fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186239/jquery-click-event-on-radio-button-doesnt-get-fired)

```
$("input[name=Transaction_PaymentProvider]").click(function(){
    if($('input:radio[name=Transaction_PaymentProvider]:checked').val() == "2"){
        $('.panel-body').show();
    }else{
        $('.panel-body').hide();
    }
}
```

You will need to look at what name is generated for the radio button.  I don't remember if the name will be . or _.  http://api.jquery.com/show/ and http://api.jquery.com/hide/ go over ways you can customize the effect.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I inserted the code you provided and ran the project.  When I get to that page the section I wanted to initially hide is hidden but it doesn't show when I tick the radiobutton to show it.

Comment: did the name of the radio button change the way that I guessed it would?  Are you getting any errors in your console when you click it?

Comment: well when I tried `name=Transaction.PaymentProvider` instead it did not hide the section.  So the name seems to be right im not sure

Comment: make sure you have the if in a click event,  see my edit above.  I also only noticed you have only one radio button in your code.  If you only have one you may want to switch it to a check box so they can hide the div again if they change their mind

Comment: I just showed one as an example there are really two and the one above the one that is here is intially checked.  Im looking at the scrip name that is generated and it is `name="Transaction.PaymentProvider"`.  So right now I have this inside the code `if ($('input:radio[name=Transaction.PaymentProvider]:checked').val() == "2") {
            $('.panel-body').show();
        } else {
            $('.panel-body').hide();
        }`

Comment: make sure to add the click event around the if

Comment: I have this now `$("#Transaction_PaymentProvider").click(function () {
            if ($('input:radio[name=Transaction_PaymentProvider]:checked').val() == "2")
            {
                $('.panel-body').show();
            }
            else 
            {
                $('.panel-body').hide();
            }
        })`

Comment: look at the source on the page.  I don't know that both radio buttons will have the same id for that click event to work.  if you run this in firefox with firebug you can walk through the script running to make sure that the click event is getting hit and the value is being selected correctly

Comment: yea I debugged with IE and saw that the name is exactly the same as eachother.  Logically your code is right just that its not reacting when the radiobuttons change more than once. Like if I tick B then tick A it hides but if I tick B afterwards then nothing happens

Comment: Not sure why it stops working,  you might try changing it from show/hide to addClass("hidden")/removeClass("hidden").  Then set up a hidden class in your css that just has display: none; and add or remove the class.  See if that helps

Comment: I editted my original post to show the code that IE is debugging

Comment: Have you tried this in a different browser?  Do you get any messages in your console after the first time it works?